# PagingAndSortingRepository cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, repository

I'm try to use `PagingAndSortingRepository` from **Spring Data**:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {}
```

But I receive this error:

> `org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository`
> can't be resolved

What wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Ant resolution on this issue? im have the same problem :(

Answer (score 10):

This one solved issue for me

**Gradle**

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '2.0.1.RELEASE'
```

**Maven**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: tried formatting. but not coming as expected. it is taken from here.. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/2.0.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 7):

I resolved this including `spring-data-commons` that included `PagingAndSortingRepository`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: In the project where I don't  use maven, adding spring-data-commons-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Delete ~.m2/org/springframework.data folder and Update maven project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the jar is installed.

```
 mvn clean dependency:tree
```

2) This what did it for me: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have  `<artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>` dependency and   `<artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>` both, then this issue will occur.

Remove the `<artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>` dependency.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

What u have used is JPA Repository
but what has happened is that maven is, either has not updated all necessary files.so to fetch all files needed we can update maven so that it can fetch all files

or we can
change extend JPA Repository to crud Repository and then change it to JPA Repository
what it does is, it first access all needed files for crud and the it works well for JPA Repository

Which worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).