# Not able to use JpaReposiory?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have already added the mysql connector dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I have made a repository package and made an interface in it.

in that when I made an Interface, name Teacher

```
public interface TeacherRepository extends  JpaRe
```

when I press ctrl + space it is not auto completing meaning there is no available interface like that.

What could be the problem?

Comment: what is Jpare ?

Comment: was trying to put in "JpaReposiotry"; autocompleting using ctrl + space.

Comment: `JPARepository` is part of spring-data-jpa. You need to include that dependency

Comment: @pvpkiran why not spring boot start one?

Comment: Because adding a database dependency doesn't mean you want to use spring data.. you can communicate with database from a spring application even without spring-data. So spring-boot doesn't make this assumption.

Comment: I meant this one, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have already parent dependency like that

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

JpaRepository coming with this dependency in springboot:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

try this hope will helpful

Comment: getting error
The type org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: you probably has issue about download correctly the libs. 
try this on command line: 
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean install

Answer (score 2):

if you want use `JpaRepository` you must add Spring-data-jpa Dependency

Put this dependency to pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

For more information you can check [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories)

Comment: getting error
The type org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: what about spring boot start as the other answer said?

Comment: yeah,maybe he's right you need to clean reinstall dependencies.In addition, another person to face on same error you can [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581212/the-type-org-springframework-data-repository-pagingandsortingrepository-cannot-b)